# Multiple controllers with one route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller which I want to deprecate but the deprecation can't be sudden. I will create a new controller and slowly migrate users from old controller to new controller. I don't want to change the routes, basically same route should be able to direct to old controller or new controller depending on a flag. Currently I am thinking of using `redirect_to` to give the control to the new controller from the old one. I want to figure out the cleanest possible way to do this. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I think the redirect_to in the old controller is your best option. Adding a before_action method would be the cleanest way.

Comment: I recommend using Rails router constraints. They allow you to define a condition on which a certain route should be triggered, so you can define the same route twice, attach a constraint to the first one, and if the condition is not fulfilled, it will trigger the 2nd one instead. You can read more about it here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: `redirect_to` only works for GET requests, or if you want to redirect every other http method as a GET request which is a very unappealing idea.

Comment: Unable to use the method suggested by @GregoryWitek since I will have to authenticate the user before checking my db for deciding where to redirect.